# Sublime text show path content

Tags: path, sublimetext2, sublimetext3, sublimetext, sublime-text-plugin

Is there a setting or package that allows sublime text 2/3 to show what's in a path? For example I type `app/` it shows me whatever is in `app/` so I can press enter to select that file or folder.

Thanks,
Jordy

Answer (score 0):

There is a package called FileSystem Autocompletion, which looks like it should show autocompletion entries based on files and folders that match the path you type - see https://packagecontrol.io/packages/FileSystem%20Autocompletion

EDIT: If that doesn't work for you, there are 2 more similar packages you could try:

- https://packagecontrol.io/packages/FuzzyFilePath
- https://packagecontrol.io/packages/AutoFileName

Comment: Nope, only picks things such as `windows` and `program files`, nothing relevant to my project